# How to udpate a choice value on a list item in Sharepoint using java SDK

Tags: java, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am developing a tool in java to transfer data from legacy applications to MS Sharepoint. I currently use the msgraph java SDK. Most things work fine, but I am having trouble updating a collection (option) property.

Using the REST API, I can update that column with the following payload:

URI: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites//lists//items//fields

```
{
    "myCollectionField@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
    "myCollectionField": [
        "VALUE 1",
        "VALUE 2"
    ]
}
```

The problem is how to do it using the Java API. All properties are defined as a JsonElement property with a string key. Ex:

```
    ListItem listItem = new ListItem();

    FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
    fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("atribute",value);
```

Simply adding the attributes will create a body with all values, but without the odata.type portion.

Is there any call in the API to add that "odata.type" portion to the body?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search and tries, my conclusion is that there is no "easy" way to add the odata directive using the API.

The attribute containing the odata directive must be added by your own code.

Using the question's example:

```
{
    "myCollectionField@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
    "myCollectionField": [
        "VALUE 1",
        "VALUE 2"
    ]
}
```

Your code must create an object like this:

```
ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
FieldValueSet fieldValueSet = new FieldValueSet();
//assume value is a collection converted to a JsonElement object
fieldValueSet.additionalDataManager().put("myCollectionField",value);
fieldValueSet.put("myCollectionField@odata.type", "Collection(Edm.String)");
```

Well, that's it. There is no helper method, and unfortunately no hints at all in the library's docs.